# Перехват исключений в фильтре

Tags: c#, mvc, filter, exception-handler

Приложение ASP.NET MVC
Методы контроллера разные:

- Возвращают JSON-ответ, например {status:**0**, message:"Данные успешно сохранены"}
- Возвращают JSON в формате Javascript-библиотеки datatables.net

При этом могут возникать два вида ошибок:

- Ошибка в бизнес-логике: от пользователя пришли некорректные данные и ему нужно возвратить такой JSON: {status:**1**, message:"Не указана дата ..."}
- Ошибка системы (некорректный SQL-запрос, потеря связи с БД, прочая runtime ошибка) - в этом случае пользователю нужно возвратить JSON {status:**1**, message:"Что-то пошло не так, попробуйте позднее"}, а подробности исключения сохранить в log-файл (возможно с отправкой сообщения администратору)

Не хотелось бы в коде контроллеров густо рассыпать try-catch, есть мысль ошибки валидации данных бросать исключениями, отлавливать их и системые ошибки в одном месте.

Возможно ли реализовать такое с помощью фильтров или как-то ещё?

Answer (score 0):

Да, это можно сделать. 
Нужно реализовать интерфейс IExceptionFilter и полученный класс применить к нужным контроллерам.
Вот ссылка на статью с примерами и описанием: [Фильтры исключений](https://professorweb.ru/my/ASP_NET/mvc/level5/5_4.php)

При необходимости можно применить фильтр глобально. Пример:

```
using System.Web.Mvc;
namespace WebApp2.Config
{
    public class FilterConfig
    {
        public static void RegisterGlobalFilters(GlobalFilterCollection filters)
        {
            filters.Add(new RangeExceptionAttribute());
        }
    }
}
```

Этот код вызывается из Global.asax

```
public class MvcApplication : System.Web.HttpApplication
{
    protected void Application_Start()
    {
        FilterConfig.RegisterGlobalFilters(GlobalFilters.Filters);
        // Другая инициализация.
    }
}
```

Внутри обработчика OnException ты можешь проанализировать исключение и сделать необходимые действия. 
Если тебе нужно реализовать разную логику реакции на разные исключения, ты можешь добавить несколько фильтров.